# What settings on HAProxy needed to work with AWS ALB (Application Load Balancer)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, haproxy, elastic-load-balancer

Currently, we have 200 containers(several different applications) running in mesos-marathon cluster. This is behind the HAproxy instances and works on HTTP/HTTPS protocol.

Internet --> *AWS ELB* --> HAProxy --> Docker containers

Now we have a requirement to make one existing application to run on WEBSOCKET protocol. We are thinking to add new AWS ALB to achieve this. Hence the setup will be like

```
        (WebSocket)
Internet --> new AWS ALB --> HAProxy --> Docker containers

        (HTTP/S)
Internet -->  AWS ELB  --> HAProxy --> Docker containers
```

What setting do we need to make so that HAproxy will work with current HTTP/S and also new WEBSOCKET?

Answer (score -1):

> The server can handle 65,536 sockets per single IP address. So the
>   quantity can be easily extended by adding additional network
>   interfaces to a server. Meanwhile, it’s extremely important to track
>   how many connections present on a server. Once the limit is exceeded,
>   you can have a lot of issues with other TCP connections (e.g. it’s not
>   possible to connect to a server via ssh). So it’s a good idea to limit
>   WS connections per node inside your application’s code.

To make HAProxy handle more than 65k connections we should pass through the next steps::

1. Create a bunch of private IP addresses. To do it choose your Amazon
   Instance -> Actions -> Networking -> Manage Private IP Addresses. We
   added 3 IP addresses: 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3. Just
   remember that the IP should be in the same sub-network as your real
   application server.
2. Connect to your HAProxy instance via SSH and run following commands:

   `$> ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.1.1`

   `$> ifconfig eth0:2 192.168.1.2`

   `$> ifconfig eth0:3 192.168.1.3`

This will add 3 virtual network interfaces to the instance.

3. Configure HAProxy. Here is a section from haproxy.cfg file for 3
   nodes accepting WS connections:

   listen erlang_front :8888

   ```
   mode        http

   balance     roundrobin

   timeout connect 1s

   timeout queue 5s

   timeout server 3600s

   option httpclose

   option forwardfor

   server      xxxxx-1 192.168.0.1:8888  source 192.168.1.1

   server      xxxxx-2 192.168.0.2:8888  source 192.168.1.2

   server      xxxxx-3 192.168.0.3:8888  source 192.168.1.3
   ```

Now HAProxy can handle more than 65,536 WebSocket connections, and the limit of connections can be easily increased by adding virtual network interfaces. Also, it can establish new connections rather fast.

Also Refer [this Blog Post](https://dzone.com/articles/load-balancing-of-websocket-connections)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you would benefit from using the new Network Load Balancer instead of the classic Elastic Load Balancer or the Application Load Balancer.

The NLB can handle (according to AWS) 10's of millions of requests per second, and supports long-lived connections.